# Idiomatic way to shallow clone or copy a map in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I want to shallow copy a map in my script so that I can update one of its keys. One way to do it is using spread operator. However, my script runs in Jenkins pipeline where spread operator is not allowed per company policy.

I try using `clone()` method, which works, but there is a warning "Access to 'clone' exceeds its access rights" in Intellij. It is partly because the map object is created from Jenkins `readJSON` method that may return map-like object and `clone()` method may not be implemented.

What is more idiomatic way to shallow copy a map other than spread operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collectEntries(Closure.IDENTITY)` - there is no no-arg version for maps, you have to pass in some version of an identity-fn

Answer (score 3):

I found a shorter way to shadow copy a map. Basically adding an empty map to the original map. See below.

```
def original = [a: 1, b: 1]

def clone = original + [:]

assert clone == original
assert !clone.is(original)
```